# Android Multiple image move resizing issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to move rotate and resize images in my android application, i've found this code from stackoverflow and its working perfectly for my requirement.... but now i need to move two images so this code will duplicate first image movements when i switched to the second image..
**1)how can i do thats...
2)i tried to add separate on touch listeners for these two images, but none of the images didn't move at all**

```
        iv_choose_hats = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_chooseHats);
        iv_choose_hats.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); // set the image scale type for compatible for onTouch movements
        iv_choose_hats.setOnTouchListener(this);

            selected_hatImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_selectedHat);
            selected_hatImage.setOnTouchListener(this);
            selected_hatImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

    // Dump touch event to log
    dumpEvent(event);

    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
             savedMatrix.set(matrix);
             start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
             mode = DRAG;
             lastEvent = null;

             break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);         
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;

            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount()==2) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);

            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            if (newDist > 10f) {              
               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            } 
            if (lastEvent!=null){
                newRot = rotation(event); 

                float r = newRot-d;
                matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth()/2, view.getMeasuredHeight()/2);  
            }
         }
         break;
  }

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use a custom class with onTouch event for one of the imageview

```
iv_choose_hats = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_chooseHats);
iv_choose_hats.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
iv_choose_hats.setOnTouchListener(new Image_OnTouch());

public class Image_OnTouch implements OnTouchListener { 
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

   }
}
```